# Assigning role to newly created user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to assign role to user at the time of account creation. . .
my code

```
protected void registerUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newUser = Membership.GetUser(registerUser.UserName);
        newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
        Roles.AddUserToRole(newUser, admin);
        ConvertControls();
        InsertinTable();


    }
```

But it give me an error:
The name "admin" does not exsist in current context.
I've created the role using ASP.net Configuration Tool
plz help me!!!
Thanx

Comment: Are u assigning roles while creating the user?

Comment: @ Bhushan Firake: Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line to this:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(newUser.UserName, "Admin"); // Role you created
```

This should work for you. The thing is that you don't have any variable `admin` , may be you wanted to Add `newUser` in `Admin` role.

So, your function will be like this:

```
protected void registerUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  newUser = Membership.GetUser(registerUser.UserName);
  newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
  Roles.AddUserToRole(newUser.UserName, "Admin");
  ConvertControls();
  InsertinTable();
}
```

Comment: :Tried it. . .Give this error
Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' to 'string'

Comment: Error removed. . Thank you so much :)

Comment: @user2295957 What is your `registerUser`?

Comment: Its an ID of asp:createdUserWizard

Comment: @ Bhushan Firake : 
  newUser = Membership.GetUser(registerUser.UserName);
        newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;

Comment: @user2295957 Yes, these are the lines i am talking about. Why do you need these variables? You haven't used `newUserId` anywhere?

Comment: I am using newUserId to store additional information in seperate table

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined admin as a variable in that context, that's why you're getting the error.

Enclose admin in quotes like this: "admin" so the compiler doesn't treat it as a variable

Comment: :Tried it. . .Give this error
Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' to 'string'